# Sticky previews is nothing but black screen

Tags: windows

Sticky previews is nothing but black screen

[image]

OS is windows 8.1 64-bit

I downloaded it here http://www.ntwind.com/blog/sticky-previews-v1.7-support-for-windows-8.1-and-10.html

still doesn't work properly.